# Access YouTube Data API with Angular/Typescript 6 Framework does not return data

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to use the YouTube Data API to get somebodies own channel information after they sign in with their Google Account.
I Can load the the YouTube Data API perfectly as well as login the user in. However fetching YouTube Data is not working.

I created a separate Authentication Service to login and fetch youtube data.

Constructor

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.initClient();
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
  }
```

Initialising the data

```
initClient() {
  gapi.load('client', () => {
    console.log('loaded client');
      gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: 'my key',
      clientId: 'my client id',
      discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'],
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
    });
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', () => console.log('loaded youtube'));
  });
}
```

Login Method

```
async login() {
      const googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      const googleUser = await googleAuth.signIn();
      const token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      console.log('my google user');
      console.log(googleUser);
      const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
      await this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
}
```

My Async getYoutubeData Method

```
async getYoutubeInfo() {
  const events = await gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    mine: true,
    part: 'contentDetails, snippets, statistics'
  });
  console.log(events);
  //this.youtubeItems = events.result.items;
}
```

Login is working perfectly but it seems the getYoutubeInfo() Method is not executing. Console remains empty.

Comment: Does the network tab show the GET being made to Google, and what is the response? Are you sure that `gapi.client.youtube.channels.list` returns a Promise? and in fact that it performs the GET rather than simply build a request with an `.execute()` method?

Comment: Hi @pinoyyid, thanks for the reply. gapi is promised based [gapi](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises) so I think I can set it up as an async function. However I cannot find a separate get request in the network tab of the browser...